# Xdebug 3 breaks a connection after removing breakpoint in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I've installed Xdebug 3.0.0 and Xdebug breaks a connection after removing breakpoint in PhpStorm.

Example scenario:

- I set two breakpoints in PhpStorm: first line, second line.
- I make a request and PhpStorm stop the code on the first breakpoint (first line).
- At this moment (when there is a connection and I can see variables) I remove that first breakpoint (on the first line).
- In the Xdebug 2.x.x the connection was still in place and I can debug code further, but in the Xdebug 3.0.0 the connection is lost. I have to make a new request and then PhpStorm stop on the second breakpoint (second line) as the first one was removed.

Do you know why?
I've searched the Xdebug documentation and couldn't find any info.

Xdebug 3.0.0 log:

```
[8] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_remove -i 40 -d 80014
```

File */usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini* content:

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

Environment:

- PhpStorm 2020.2.4.
- macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Docker Desktop Community 2.5.0.1
- docker 19.03.13
- docker-compose 1.27.4

Comment: It's a bug in Xdebug. Fixed for 3.0.1

Comment: If you need to use Xdebug v3 and cannot wait for 3.0.1 release then try building latest from sources if you can (it confirmed to be working in master by few people) -- https://xdebug.org/docs/install#source (sorry, no help from me on this)

Comment: FYI: Xdebug 3.0.1 has been released today